# Property 'NameNews' does not exist on type using ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

interface

```js
export interface  INewsModule{

   IDNews:number;
   IDCategoery:number; 
   NameNews:string; 
   TopicNews:string; 
   DateNews?:Date;
     ImageCaption:string;
    ImageName:string ;


}
```

Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../../serv/news.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { INewsModule } from '../../Class/i-news/i-news.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {Http , Response , Headers , RequestOptions ,RequestMethod, } from '@angular/http';
import { ISubscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { retry } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/retry';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalis',
  templateUrl: './detalis.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalis.component.scss'],
  providers:[NewsService]
})
export class DetalisComponent implements OnInit {
 public Newsmodule : INewsModule[];
  subscription: ISubscription;
  statusMessage: string = 'please wait Loading data ... :D';
       items :INewsModule[]=[];

     constructor(public _NewsService : NewsService,public _activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,public _HttpClient: HttpClient    
      ) { }
      ngOnInit() {
          let id : number = this._activeRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
          this._NewsService.getdetails(id).retryWhen((err) => {
            return err.scan((retryCount) =>{
  retryCount +=1;
  if(retryCount < 6 ){
  this.statusMessage ='Retrying .....Attept #' + retryCount;
  return retryCount;
  } else {
  throw (err);
  }
  }, 0).delay(1000)
  })
    .subscribe((newsdata) => {
      if(newsdata == null){
        this.statusMessage = 'Employee code does not exist';
      } else {
          this.items = newsdata
      }
  
      },
      (error) =>{
        this.statusMessage = "please try again after sometime"
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
  }
```

Template DetalisComponent
Template DetalisComponent
Template DetalisComponent
Template DetalisComponent
Template DetalisComponent
Template DetalisComponent
Template DetalisComponent
Update

```html
      <table class="blueTable" style="height: 212px;" width="333">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th>NameNews</th>
                  <th>TopicNews</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Image</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                  <td colspan="4">
                  <div class="links">&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr  >

                <td>{{items.NameNews}}</td>
                  <td>{{items.TopicNews}}</td>
                  <td>{{items.DateNews}}</td>
                  <td><img class="" src="http://localhost:56181/Image/{{items.ImageName}}"> </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
```

```js
/GetdetailsNews
    getdetails(id:number): Observable <INewsModule[]>{
      return   this.http.get('http://localhost:56181/api/details/' + id).map((response: Response)=><INewsModule[]>response.json());
      }
```

i using routing

Index => allCategory => allnews => detailsNews[name,date....]
using
ng s --o

project run successfully

but in deploy project using

ng build --prod 
show Errors

```js
ERROR in src\app\views\home\detalis.component.html(126,21): : Property 'NameNews' does not exist on type 'INewsModule[]'.
src\app\views\home\detalis.component.html(127,23): : Property 'TopicNews' does not exist on type 'INewsModule[]'.
src\app\views\home\detalis.component.html(128,23): : Property 'DateNews' does not exist on type 'INewsModule[]'.
src\app\views\home\detalis.component.html(129,37): : Property 'ImageName' does not exist on type 'INewsModule[]'.
```

Comment: Hi there, the error is in the HTML, could you please put here the HTML so I can see it?

Comment: I added
html in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error come from the fact that the variable 'items' is typed as an array of elements of type 'INewsModule' (when declared in the component). You probably need to iterate on this array, or to change the type of this variable.

Comment: thank you now work   change  INewsModule[]   to       INewsModule      thank you